# "Прыгающий" виджет во Flutter

Tags: flutter, стек

Есть navbar с tabs. На одном из табов строится небольшой радиальный график, с помощью stack на график помещаются пояснения.
Работает все прекрасно до тех пор, пока нажатиями на вкладки в navbar не начинаешь "ходить" по другим вкладкам. Как только возвращаешься назад на tab, где прописан график, виджет с тектом (разъяснение) на долю секунды оказывается в верхнем левом углу корневого для него виджета (stack у меня вложен в container), а потом появляется в нужном месте. Раздражает жутко, конечно.

В чем может быть дело?

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState> _chartKey =
      new GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState>();

  final GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState> _chartKey2 =
      new GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState>();

  final currentWeightKey = GlobalKey();
  final chartKeyContainer = GlobalKey();
  final startWeightKey = GlobalKey();
  final endWeightKey = GlobalKey();

  Size size = Size(0, 0);
  Size size2 = Size(0, 0);
  Size sizeOfChartContainer = Size(0, 0);

  Size sizeOfEndWeight = Size(0, 0);
  double deltaOfEndWeight = 0.0;

  Size sizeOfCurrentWeight = Size(0, 0);
  double deltaOfCurrentWeightSize = 0.0;

  Size sizeOfStartWeight = Size(0, 0);
  double deltaOfStartWeight = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    calculateSizeOfWidget();
    super.initState();
  }

 void calculateSizeOfWidget() =>
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        final RenderBox boxChartContainer =
            chartKeyContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        final RenderBox boxCurrentWeight =
            currentWeightKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        final RenderBox boxStartWeight =
            startWeightKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
        final RenderBox boxEndWeight =
            endWeightKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();

        setState(() {
          sizeOfCurrentWeight = boxCurrentWeight.size;
          deltaOfCurrentWeightSize = sizeOfCurrentWeight.width / 2;

          sizeOfChartContainer = boxChartContainer.size;

          sizeOfStartWeight = boxStartWeight.size;
          deltaOfStartWeight = sizeOfStartWeight.width / 2;

          sizeOfEndWeight = boxEndWeight.size;
          deltaOfEndWeight = sizeOfEndWeight.width / 2;
        });
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Сводная информация"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Text("Прогресс"),
            Container(
              key: chartKeyContainer,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  RotationTransition(
                    turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(270 / 360),
                    child: AnimatedCircularChart(
                      key: _chartKey,
                      size: const Size(200.0, 200.0),
                      initialChartData: <CircularStackEntry>[
                        new CircularStackEntry(
                          <CircularSegmentEntry>[
                            new CircularSegmentEntry(
                              50,
                              Colors.grey[300],
                              rankKey: 'remaining',
                            ),
                          ],
                          rankKey: 'progress',
                        ),
                      ],
                      chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
                      edgeStyle: SegmentEdgeStyle.round,
                      percentageValues: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  RotationTransition(
                    turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(270 / 360),
                    child: AnimatedCircularChart(
                      key: _chartKey2,
                      size: const Size(200.0, 200.0),
                      initialChartData: <CircularStackEntry>[
                        new CircularStackEntry(
                          <CircularSegmentEntry>[
                            new CircularSegmentEntry(
                              11.3,
                              Colors.red[300],
                              rankKey: '1',
                            ),
                          ],
                          rankKey: '2',
                        ),
                      ],
                      chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
                      edgeStyle: SegmentEdgeStyle.round,
                      percentageValues: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Positioned(
                  //   key: leftTextChartKey,
                  //   top: 110,
                  //   left: size.width.toInt() / 4,
                  //   child: Container(
                  //     child: Text("ВЕС1"),
                  //     color: Colors.red[100],
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  Positioned(
                    key: currentWeightKey,
                    top: sizeOfChartContainer.height / 4,
                    left: sizeOfChartContainer.width / 2 -
                        deltaOfCurrentWeightSize,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "102",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 32,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text("-10 кг"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    key: startWeightKey,
                    top: sizeOfChartContainer.height / 2 + 7,
                    left: 17 - deltaOfStartWeight / 2,
                    child: Text(
                      "120",
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    key: endWeightKey,
                    top: sizeOfChartContainer.height / 2 + 7,
                    right: 13,
                    child: Text("90"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Код страницы с навбаром:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int currentTab = 0;

  final List<Widget> screens = [
    GraphicsPage(),
    InfoPage(),
    DashboardPage(),
    SomethingPage(),
  ];

  Widget currentScreen = DashboardPage();
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = DashboardPage();
                        currentTab = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.dashboard,
                          color: currentTab == 0
                              ? Colors.greenAccent
                              : Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Сводная",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 0
                                ? Colors.greenAccent
                                : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = GraphicsPage();
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.graphic_eq,
                          color: currentTab == 1
                              ? Colors.greenAccent
                              : Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Графики",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 1
                                ? Colors.greenAccent
                                : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = InfoPage();
                        currentTab = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.info,
                          color: currentTab == 2
                              ? Colors.greenAccent
                              : Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "О замерах",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 2
                                ? Colors.greenAccent
                                : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = SomethingPage();
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.face,
                          color: currentTab == 3
                              ? Colors.greenAccent
                              : Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Что-то",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 3
                                ? Colors.greenAccent
                                : Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Проблема может быть в navbar... Где его код?

Comment: Подсказка: при переходе на другие табы, старые табы могут удаляться и перестраиваться заново.

Comment: добавил код страницы с навбаром.

Comment: `currentScreen = DashboardPage();` при переходе вы каждый раз пересоздаете виджет.

Comment: Не уверен, но может так будет работать `PageStorage(child: screens[currentTab ], ...)`

Comment: Да, спасибо! Помогло! Виной всему была строчка currentScreen = DashboardPage();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Перенос ответа из комментариев, чтобы закрыть вопрос.*

Проблема в `currentScreen = DashboardPage();` при переходе вы каждый раз пересоздаете виджет.

Решение проблемы:
Убрать присвоение `currentScreen` и

```
body: PageStorage(
  child: screens[currentTab],
  bucket: bucket,
),
```